# How can I hide Vue code in a non SPA Django and Vue project?

Tags: django, vue.js, vue-component

I am working on a Django web app and have used Vue components inside it. Everything is fine but my only concern is that I don’t want the source code to be visible in production .

I don’t want to go by the full SPA route as it will take a lot of time and effort. Can I make the code less human readable ?

See if i view it in the browser then it’s completely readable and I would not like it this way in production

[image: Screenshot of the view source in the browser]

Please help me here !!

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

As its all client-side code, except perhaps your *all_timesheet_json* this can come from an endpoint with appropriate permissions, but, you can use a tool that "minifies" your JavaScript:

https://javascript-minifier.com/

This will make your code harder to read, but will make your file smaller.
Only downside is that it will be harder to make changes to your code, you will have to make another copy as a "development" version and the minified as a "production" version.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to procoib's suggestion of minification as a concept, you're probably going to find that you want to bundle those numerous CDN calls and your own Javascript code into one or two files once you get to production. Something like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/) will allow you to set up a consistent routine to bundle your files together and minify them. This also allows you to incorporate things like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to write more readable and maintainable Javascript.

Comment: Hi Riley , I've used webpack and Babel with the CLI version of an other project. How can i use webpack here ? What are the benefits of that ? Any link of a working example will be helpful.

Comment: Hi there, minification is actually a preset within babel-loader, and it's easy to add additional steps if you'd like to otherwise package your code.